# Can not able to save html code in Asp.net core web api

Tags: html, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to insert `html` code to `sql` server by using string property.I am using `Json` `Api` for crud operation. From my research i found that allow `html` no more so i implement  `HtmlEncoder`, `JavaScriptEncoder`, `UrlEncoder` but still i can not able to sent html code. please anyone help me.

**`Controller` class**:

```html
  private readonly IInvoiceTemplateService _invoiceTemplateService;
        private ILog _logger;
      private   HtmlEncoder _htmlEncoder;
       private JavaScriptEncoder _javaScriptEncoder;
      private  UrlEncoder _urlEncoder;
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor - InvoiceTemplate Controller
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="jsonApiContext"></param>
        /// <param name="invoiceTemplateService"></param>
        /// <param name="dbContext"></param>
        public InvoiceTemplateController(
                IJsonApiContext jsonApiContext,
        IInvoiceTemplateService invoiceTemplateService,
         ILog logger,
          HtmlEncoder htmlEncoder,
           JavaScriptEncoder javascriptEncoder,
           UrlEncoder urlEncoder)
        : base(jsonApiContext, invoiceTemplateService)
        {
            _invoiceTemplateService = invoiceTemplateService;
            _logger = logger;
            _htmlEncoder = htmlEncoder;
            _javaScriptEncoder = javascriptEncoder;
            _urlEncoder = urlEncoder;
        }
```

**`entity` class**:

```html
 [Attr("InvoiceTemplateBody")]
 public string InvoiceTemplateBody { get; set; }
```

**input**:
[image: input]

**error**:
[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is `<head name="">`. Since the double quotes character `"` is a reserved character in JSON, you need to properly escape it like this `\"`. So the solution to your question is to send

```
{
  "invoicetemplatebody": "<head name=\"\">"
}
```

P.S.: You had an extra comma at the end of your JSON field which I removed since there are no more fields.

Comment: so ,from front end ,i need to do the HtmlEncoder, JavaScriptEncoder, UrlEncoder encoder right??